# Counting equivalence relations on set of $n$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I know for a fact that the number of equivalence relations on a n element set is defined by the Bell Number.

For the case of $n=4$ the number would be then 15. But question is how do we count them?

If I understood correctly, equivalence relations in this case comprise of only 2 elements per relation?

So I start off with $(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3),(2,4), (3,4)$ and multiply by 2 because of symmetry and add $(1,1)...(4,4)$ to account for reflexivity. Transitivity has been accounted for when we multiplied the first step by 2.

Wouldn't I then get 16 instead of 15? Or is my understanding of the concept wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us list and count the ways to divide our set into **equivalence classes.**

$1.$ One equivalence class, everybody is related to everybody else. There is $1$ way only to do this.

$2.$ One family of $3$ people, and a loner. The loner can be picked in $4$ ways.

$3.$ Two couples. Alan can partner with any of the $3$ remaining people.

$4.$ One couple, and $2$ loners. The couple can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways.

$5.$ Everybody a loner, $1$ way.